# How to force vesa to 1280x1024 resolution

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, resolution

I'm using Manjaro (ArchLinux) using vesa driver, since fglrx beta crashes a lot, and radeon and fglrx stable does not support my graphic card.

I want to force my monitor resolution to the maximum (1280x1024), how to do it? Here's my xorg.conf

```
$ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf

Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier  "X.org Configured"
        Screen      0  "Scr0" 0 0
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier  "Mon0"
        VendorName  "Acer"                                                                                                                      
        ModeLine    "1280x1024_60.00" 109.0 1280 1368 1496 1712 1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync
        Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
        Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
        Option      "DPMS" "true"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        Identifier  "Gpu0"
        Driver      "vesa"
        BusID       "PCI:0:1:0"
        Option      "DRI"    "true"
        VendorName  "AMD"
        BoardName   "Radeon HD 8570D"
EndSection

Section "DRI"
  Group  "video"
  Mode   0666
EndSection 

Section "Extensions"
        Option "Composite" "Enable"
        Option "RENDER"    "Enable"
EndSection 

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier          "Keyboard Defaults"
        MatchIsKeyboard     "yes"
        Option              "XkbOptions" "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier "Scr0"
        Device     "Gpu0"
        Monitor    "Mon0"
        DefaultDepth     24
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth      24
                Modes      "1280x1024"
        EndSubSection
EndSection
```

startx `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` output:

```
[559155.270] (II) Loading sub module "vbe"
[559155.270] (II) LoadModule: "vbe"
[559155.270] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libvbe.so
[559155.270] (II) Module vbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[559155.270]    compiled for 1.14.2, module version = 1.1.0
[559155.270]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 14.1
[559155.270] (II) Loading sub module "int10"
[559155.270] (II) LoadModule: "int10"
[559155.270] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libint10.so
[559155.270] (II) Module int10: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[559155.270]    compiled for 1.14.2, module version = 1.0.0
[559155.270]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 14.1
[559155.270] (II) VESA(0): initializing int10
[559155.271] (II) VESA(0): Primary V_BIOS segment is: 0xc000
[559155.271] (II) VESA(0): VESA BIOS detected
[559155.271] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE Version 3.0
[559155.271] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE Total Mem: 16384 kB
[559155.271] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM: AMD ATOMBIOS
[559155.271] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Software Rev: 15.31
[559155.271] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Vendor: (C) 1988-2010, Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
[559155.271] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Product: DVST
[559155.271] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Product Rev: 01.00
[559155.291] (II) VESA(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[559155.291] (==) VESA(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[559155.291] (==) VESA(0): RGB weight 888
[559155.291] (==) VESA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[559155.291] (==) VESA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[559155.291] (II) Loading sub module "ddc"
[559155.291] (II) LoadModule: "ddc"
[559155.291] (II) Module "ddc" already built-in
[559155.291] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE DDC supported
[559155.291] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE DDC Level 2
[559155.291] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE DDC transfer in appr. 1 sec.
[559155.338] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE DDC unkown failure 768
[559155.338] (II) VESA(0): Searching for matching VESA mode(s):
*snip*
[559155.343] Mode: 107 (1280x1024)
[559155.343]    ModeAttributes: 0xba
[559155.343]    WinAAttributes: 0x7
[559155.343]    WinBAttributes: 0x0
[559155.343]    WinGranularity: 64
[559155.343]    WinSize: 64
[559155.343]    WinASegment: 0xa000
[559155.343]    WinBSegment: 0x0
[559155.343]    WinFuncPtr: 0xc000594d
[559155.343]    BytesPerScanline: 1280
[559155.343]    XResolution: 1280
[559155.343]    YResolution: 1024
[559155.343]    XCharSize: 8
[559155.343]    YCharSize: 16
[559155.343]    NumberOfPlanes: 1
[559155.343]    BitsPerPixel: 8
[559155.343]    NumberOfBanks: 1
[559155.343]    MemoryModel: 4
[559155.343]    BankSize: 0
[559155.343]    NumberOfImages: 11
[559155.343]    RedMaskSize: 0
[559155.343]    RedFieldPosition: 0
[559155.343]    GreenMaskSize: 0
[559155.343]    GreenFieldPosition: 0
[559155.343]    BlueMaskSize: 0
[559155.343]    BlueFieldPosition: 0
[559155.343]    RsvdMaskSize: 0
[559155.343]    RsvdFieldPosition: 0
[559155.343]    DirectColorModeInfo: 0
[559155.343]    PhysBasePtr: 0xc0000000
[559155.343]    LinBytesPerScanLine: 1280
[559155.343]    BnkNumberOfImagePages: 11
[559155.343]    LinNumberOfImagePages: 11
[559155.343]    LinRedMaskSize: 0
[559155.343]    LinRedFieldPosition: 0
[559155.343]    LinGreenMaskSize: 0
[559155.343]    LinGreenFieldPosition: 0
[559155.343]    LinBlueMaskSize: 0
[559155.343]    LinBlueFieldPosition: 0
[559155.343]    LinRsvdMaskSize: 0
[559155.343]    LinRsvdFieldPosition: 0
[559155.343]    MaxPixelClock: 400000000
*snip*
[559155.349] Mode: 116 (1024x768)
[559155.349]    ModeAttributes: 0xbb
[559155.349]    WinAAttributes: 0x7
[559155.349]    WinBAttributes: 0x0
[559155.349]    WinGranularity: 64
[559155.349]    WinSize: 64
[559155.349]    WinASegment: 0xa000
[559155.349]    WinBSegment: 0x0
[559155.349]    WinFuncPtr: 0xc000594d
[559155.349]    BytesPerScanline: 2048
[559155.349]    XResolution: 1024
[559155.349]    YResolution: 768
[559155.349]    XCharSize: 8
[559155.349]    YCharSize: 16
[559155.349]    NumberOfPlanes: 1
[559155.349]    BitsPerPixel: 16
[559155.349]    NumberOfBanks: 1
[559155.349]    MemoryModel: 6
[559155.349]    BankSize: 0
[559155.349]    NumberOfImages: 9
[559155.349]    RedMaskSize: 5
[559155.349]    RedFieldPosition: 10
[559155.349]    GreenMaskSize: 5
[559155.349]    GreenFieldPosition: 5
[559155.349]    BlueMaskSize: 5
[559155.349]    BlueFieldPosition: 0
[559155.349]    RsvdMaskSize: 0
[559155.349]    RsvdFieldPosition: 0
[559155.349]    DirectColorModeInfo: 0
[559155.349]    PhysBasePtr: 0xc0000000
[559155.349]    LinBytesPerScanLine: 2048
[559155.349]    BnkNumberOfImagePages: 9
[559155.349]    LinNumberOfImagePages: 9
[559155.349]    LinRedMaskSize: 5
[559155.349]    LinRedFieldPosition: 10
[559155.349]    LinGreenMaskSize: 5
[559155.349]    LinGreenFieldPosition: 5
[559155.349]    LinBlueMaskSize: 5
[559155.349]    LinBlueFieldPosition: 0
[559155.349]    LinRsvdMaskSize: 0
[559155.349]    LinRsvdFieldPosition: 0
[559155.349]    MaxPixelClock: 400000000
[559155.350] Mode: 117 (1024x768)
[559155.350]    ModeAttributes: 0xbb
[559155.350]    WinAAttributes: 0x7
[559155.350]    WinBAttributes: 0x0
[559155.350]    WinGranularity: 64
[559155.350]    WinSize: 64
[559155.350]    WinASegment: 0xa000
[559155.350]    WinBSegment: 0x0
[559155.350]    WinFuncPtr: 0xc000594d
[559155.350]    BytesPerScanline: 2048
[559155.350]    XResolution: 1024
[559155.350]    YResolution: 768
[559155.350]    XCharSize: 8
[559155.350]    YCharSize: 16
[559155.350]    NumberOfPlanes: 1
[559155.350]    BitsPerPixel: 16
[559155.350]    NumberOfBanks: 1
[559155.350]    MemoryModel: 6
[559155.350]    BankSize: 0
[559155.350]    NumberOfImages: 9
[559155.350]    RedMaskSize: 5
[559155.350]    RedFieldPosition: 11
[559155.350]    GreenMaskSize: 6
[559155.350]    GreenFieldPosition: 5
[559155.350]    BlueMaskSize: 5
[559155.350]    BlueFieldPosition: 0
[559155.350]    RsvdMaskSize: 0
[559155.350]    RsvdFieldPosition: 0
[559155.350]    DirectColorModeInfo: 0
[559155.350]    PhysBasePtr: 0xc0000000
[559155.350]    LinBytesPerScanLine: 2048
[559155.350]    BnkNumberOfImagePages: 9
[559155.350]    LinNumberOfImagePages: 9
[559155.350]    LinRedMaskSize: 5
[559155.350]    LinRedFieldPosition: 11
[559155.350]    LinGreenMaskSize: 6
[559155.350]    LinGreenFieldPosition: 5
[559155.350]    LinBlueMaskSize: 5
[559155.351]    LinBlueFieldPosition: 0
[559155.351]    LinRsvdMaskSize: 0
[559155.351]    LinRsvdFieldPosition: 0
[559155.351]    MaxPixelClock: 400000000
[559155.351] Mode: 119 (1280x1024)
[559155.351]    ModeAttributes: 0xba
[559155.351]    WinAAttributes: 0x7
[559155.351]    WinBAttributes: 0x0
[559155.351]    WinGranularity: 64
[559155.351]    WinSize: 64
[559155.351]    WinASegment: 0xa000
[559155.351]    WinBSegment: 0x0
[559155.351]    WinFuncPtr: 0xc000594d
[559155.351]    BytesPerScanline: 2560
[559155.351]    XResolution: 1280
[559155.351]    YResolution: 1024
[559155.351]    XCharSize: 8
[559155.351]    YCharSize: 16
[559155.351]    NumberOfPlanes: 1
[559155.351]    BitsPerPixel: 16
[559155.351]    NumberOfBanks: 1
[559155.351]    MemoryModel: 6
[559155.351]    BankSize: 0
[559155.351]    NumberOfImages: 5
[559155.351]    RedMaskSize: 5
[559155.351]    RedFieldPosition: 10
[559155.351]    GreenMaskSize: 5
[559155.351]    GreenFieldPosition: 5
[559155.351]    BlueMaskSize: 5
[559155.351]    BlueFieldPosition: 0
[559155.351]    RsvdMaskSize: 0
[559155.351]    RsvdFieldPosition: 0
[559155.351]    DirectColorModeInfo: 0
[559155.351]    PhysBasePtr: 0xc0000000
[559155.351]    LinBytesPerScanLine: 2560
[559155.351]    BnkNumberOfImagePages: 5
[559155.351]    LinNumberOfImagePages: 5
[559155.351]    LinRedMaskSize: 5
[559155.351]    LinRedFieldPosition: 10
[559155.351]    LinGreenMaskSize: 5
[559155.351]    LinGreenFieldPosition: 5
[559155.351]    LinBlueMaskSize: 5
[559155.351]    LinBlueFieldPosition: 0
[559155.351]    LinRsvdMaskSize: 0
[559155.351]    LinRsvdFieldPosition: 0
[559155.351]    MaxPixelClock: 400000000
[559155.352] Mode: 11a (1280x1024)
[559155.352]    ModeAttributes: 0xba
[559155.352]    WinAAttributes: 0x7
[559155.352]    WinBAttributes: 0x0
[559155.352]    WinGranularity: 64
[559155.352]    WinSize: 64
[559155.352]    WinASegment: 0xa000
[559155.352]    WinBSegment: 0x0
[559155.352]    WinFuncPtr: 0xc000594d
[559155.352]    BytesPerScanline: 2560
[559155.352]    XResolution: 1280
[559155.352]    YResolution: 1024
[559155.352]    XCharSize: 8
[559155.352]    YCharSize: 16
[559155.352]    NumberOfPlanes: 1
[559155.352]    BitsPerPixel: 16
[559155.352]    NumberOfBanks: 1
[559155.352]    MemoryModel: 6
[559155.352]    BankSize: 0
[559155.352]    NumberOfImages: 5
[559155.352]    RedMaskSize: 5
[559155.352]    RedFieldPosition: 11
[559155.352]    GreenMaskSize: 6
[559155.352]    GreenFieldPosition: 5
[559155.352]    BlueMaskSize: 5
[559155.352]    BlueFieldPosition: 0
[559155.352]    RsvdMaskSize: 0
[559155.352]    RsvdFieldPosition: 0
[559155.352]    DirectColorModeInfo: 0
[559155.352]    PhysBasePtr: 0xc0000000
[559155.352]    LinBytesPerScanLine: 2560
[559155.352]    BnkNumberOfImagePages: 5
[559155.352]    LinNumberOfImagePages: 5
[559155.352]    LinRedMaskSize: 5
[559155.352]    LinRedFieldPosition: 11
[559155.352]    LinGreenMaskSize: 6
[559155.352]    LinGreenFieldPosition: 5
[559155.352]    LinBlueMaskSize: 5
[559155.352]    LinBlueFieldPosition: 0
[559155.352]    LinRsvdMaskSize: 0
[559155.352]    LinRsvdFieldPosition: 0
[559155.352]    MaxPixelClock: 400000000
*snip*
[559155.358] *Mode: 123 (1024x768)
[559155.358]    ModeAttributes: 0xbb
[559155.358]    WinAAttributes: 0x7
[559155.358]    WinBAttributes: 0x0
[559155.358]    WinGranularity: 64
[559155.358]    WinSize: 64
[559155.358]    WinASegment: 0xa000
[559155.358]    WinBSegment: 0x0
[559155.358]    WinFuncPtr: 0xc000594d
[559155.358]    BytesPerScanline: 4096
[559155.358]    XResolution: 1024
[559155.358]    YResolution: 768
[559155.358]    XCharSize: 8
[559155.358]    YCharSize: 16
[559155.358]    NumberOfPlanes: 1
[559155.358]    BitsPerPixel: 32
[559155.358]    NumberOfBanks: 1
[559155.358]    MemoryModel: 6
[559155.358]    BankSize: 0
[559155.358]    NumberOfImages: 4
[559155.358]    RedMaskSize: 8
[559155.358]    RedFieldPosition: 16
[559155.358]    GreenMaskSize: 8
[559155.358]    GreenFieldPosition: 8
[559155.358]    BlueMaskSize: 8
[559155.358]    BlueFieldPosition: 0
[559155.358]    RsvdMaskSize: 0
[559155.358]    RsvdFieldPosition: 0
[559155.358]    DirectColorModeInfo: 0
[559155.358]    PhysBasePtr: 0xc0000000
[559155.358]    LinBytesPerScanLine: 4096
[559155.358]    BnkNumberOfImagePages: 4
[559155.358]    LinNumberOfImagePages: 4
[559155.358]    LinRedMaskSize: 8
[559155.358]    LinRedFieldPosition: 16
[559155.358]    LinGreenMaskSize: 8
[559155.358]    LinGreenFieldPosition: 8
[559155.358]    LinBlueMaskSize: 8
[559155.358]    LinBlueFieldPosition: 0
[559155.358]    LinRsvdMaskSize: 0
[559155.358]    LinRsvdFieldPosition: 0
[559155.358]    MaxPixelClock: 400000000
[559155.359] Mode: 124 (1280x1024)
[559155.359]    ModeAttributes: 0xba
[559155.359]    WinAAttributes: 0x7
[559155.359]    WinBAttributes: 0x0
[559155.359]    WinGranularity: 64
[559155.359]    WinSize: 64
[559155.359]    WinASegment: 0xa000
[559155.359]    WinBSegment: 0x0
[559155.359]    WinFuncPtr: 0xc000594d
[559155.359]    BytesPerScanline: 5120
[559155.359]    XResolution: 1280
[559155.359]    YResolution: 1024
[559155.359]    XCharSize: 8
[559155.359]    YCharSize: 16
[559155.359]    NumberOfPlanes: 1
[559155.359]    BitsPerPixel: 32
[559155.359]    NumberOfBanks: 1
[559155.359]    MemoryModel: 6
[559155.359]    BankSize: 0
[559155.359]    NumberOfImages: 2
[559155.359]    RedMaskSize: 8
[559155.359]    RedFieldPosition: 16
[559155.359]    GreenMaskSize: 8
[559155.359]    GreenFieldPosition: 8
[559155.359]    BlueMaskSize: 8
[559155.359]    BlueFieldPosition: 0
[559155.359]    RsvdMaskSize: 0
[559155.359]    RsvdFieldPosition: 0
[559155.359]    DirectColorModeInfo: 0
[559155.359]    PhysBasePtr: 0xc0000000
[559155.359]    LinBytesPerScanLine: 5120
[559155.359]    BnkNumberOfImagePages: 2
[559155.359]    LinNumberOfImagePages: 2
[559155.359]    LinRedMaskSize: 8
[559155.359]    LinRedFieldPosition: 16
[559155.359]    LinGreenMaskSize: 8
[559155.359]    LinGreenFieldPosition: 8
[559155.359]    LinBlueMaskSize: 8
[559155.359]    LinBlueFieldPosition: 0
[559155.359]    LinRsvdMaskSize: 0
[559155.359]    LinRsvdFieldPosition: 0
[559155.359]    MaxPixelClock: 400000000
*snip*
[559155.364] (II) VESA(0): Total Memory: 256 64KB banks (16384kB)
[559155.364] (II) VESA(0): <default monitor>: Using default hsync range of 31.50-48.00 kHz
[559155.364] (II) VESA(0): <default monitor>: Using default vrefresh range of 50.00-70.00 Hz
[559155.364] (II) VESA(0): <default monitor>: Using default maximum pixel clock of 65.00 MHz
[559155.364] (WW) VESA(0): Unable to estimate virtual size
[559155.364] (II) VESA(0): Not using built-in mode "1024x768" (no mode of this name)
[559155.364] (II) VESA(0): Not using built-in mode "800x600" (no mode of this name)
[559155.364] (II) VESA(0): Not using built-in mode "640x480" (no mode of this name)
[559155.364] (WW) VESA(0): No valid modes left. Trying less strict filter...
[559155.364] (II) VESA(0): <default monitor>: Using hsync range of 31.50-48.00 kHz
[559155.364] (II) VESA(0): <default monitor>: Using vrefresh range of 50.00-70.00 Hz
[559155.364] (II) VESA(0): <default monitor>: Using maximum pixel clock of 65.00 MHz
[559155.364] (WW) VESA(0): Unable to estimate virtual size
[559155.364] (--) VESA(0): Virtual size is 1024x768 (pitch 1024)
[559155.364] (**) VESA(0): *Built-in mode "1024x768"
[559155.364] (**) VESA(0): *Built-in mode "800x600"
[559155.364] (**) VESA(0): *Built-in mode "640x480"
[559155.364] (==) VESA(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[559155.364] (II) VESA(0): Attempting to use 60Hz refresh for mode "1024x768" (123)
[559155.364] (II) VESA(0): Attempting to use 60Hz refresh for mode "800x600" (122)
[559155.364] (II) VESA(0): Attempting to use 60Hz refresh for mode "640x480" (121)
[559155.364] (**) VESA(0): Using "Shadow Framebuffer"
[559155.364] (II) Loading sub module "shadow"
[559155.364] (II) LoadModule: "shadow"
[559155.365] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libshadow.so
[559155.365] (II) Module shadow: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[559155.365]    compiled for 1.14.2, module version = 1.1.0
[559155.365]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[559155.365] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[559155.365] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[559155.365] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[559155.365] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[559155.365]    compiled for 1.14.2, module version = 1.0.0
[559155.365]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[559155.365] (==) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[559155.365] (II) Loading sub module "int10"
[559155.365] (II) LoadModule: "int10"
[559155.365] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libint10.so
[559155.365] (II) Module int10: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[559155.365]    compiled for 1.14.2, module version = 1.0.0
[559155.365]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 14.1
[559155.365] (II) VESA(0): initializing int10
[559155.365] (II) VESA(0): Primary V_BIOS segment is: 0xc000
[559155.365] (II) VESA(0): VESA BIOS detected
[559155.365] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE Version 3.0
[559155.365] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE Total Mem: 16384 kB
[559155.365] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM: AMD ATOMBIOS
[559155.365] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Software Rev: 15.31
[559155.365] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Vendor: (C) 1988-2010, Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
[559155.365] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Product: DVST
[559155.365] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Product Rev: 01.00
[559155.366] (II) VESA(0): virtual address = 0xb5d08000,
    physical address = 0xc0000000, size = 16777216
[559155.524] (II) VESA(0): Setting up VESA Mode 0x123 (1024x768)
[559155.524] (II) VESA(0): VBESetVBEMode failed, mode set without customized refresh.
[559156.375] (==) VESA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[559156.375] (==) VESA(0): Backing store disabled
[559156.375] (==) VESA(0): DPMS enabled
[559156.375] (WW) VESA(0): Option "DRI" is not used
[559156.375] (==) RandR enabled
[559156.383] (II) AIGLX: Screen 0 is not DRI2 capable
[559156.383] (II) AIGLX: Screen 0 is not DRI capable
[559157.403] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized swrast
[559157.403] (II) GLX: Initialized DRISWRAST GL provider for screen 0
[559157.450] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event4)
[559157.450] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[559157.450] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "Keyboard Defaults"
[559157.450] (II) LoadModule: "evdev"
[559157.450] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[559157.450] (II) Module evdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[559157.450]    compiled for 1.14.2, module version = 2.8.1
[559157.450]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[559157.450]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 19.1
[559157.450] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[559157.450] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[559157.450] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event4"
[559157.450] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[559157.450] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[559157.450] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[559157.450] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input4/event4"
[559157.450] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[559157.450] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[559157.450] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc104"
[559157.450] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[559157.450] (**) Option "xkb_options" "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
[559157.479] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event3)
[559157.479] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[559157.479] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "Keyboard Defaults"
[559157.479] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[559157.479] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[559157.479] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event3"
[559157.479] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[559157.479] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[559157.479] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[559157.479] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input3/event3"
[559157.480] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[559157.480] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[559157.480] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc104"
[559157.480] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[559157.480] (**) Option "xkb_options" "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
[559157.480] (II) config/udev: Adding input device USB USB Keyboard (/dev/input/event1)
[559157.480] (**) USB USB Keyboard: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[559157.480] (**) USB USB Keyboard: Applying InputClass "Keyboard Defaults"
[559157.480] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'USB USB Keyboard'
[559157.480] (**) USB USB Keyboard: always reports core events
[559157.480] (**) evdev: USB USB Keyboard: Device: "/dev/input/event1"
[559157.481] (--) evdev: USB USB Keyboard: Vendor 0x1a2c Product 0xc21
[559157.481] (--) evdev: USB USB Keyboard: Found keys
[559157.481] (II) evdev: USB USB Keyboard: Configuring as keyboard
[559157.481] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb3/3-5/3-5:1.0/input/input1/event1"
[559157.481] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "USB USB Keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[559157.481] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[559157.481] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc104"
[559157.481] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[559157.481] (**) Option "xkb_options" "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
[559157.481] (II) config/udev: Adding input device USB USB Keyboard (/dev/input/event2)
[559157.481] (**) USB USB Keyboard: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[559157.482] (**) USB USB Keyboard: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[559157.482] (**) USB USB Keyboard: Applying InputClass "Keyboard Defaults"
[559157.482] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'USB USB Keyboard'
[559157.482] (**) USB USB Keyboard: always reports core events
[559157.482] (**) evdev: USB USB Keyboard: Device: "/dev/input/event2"
[559157.482] (--) evdev: USB USB Keyboard: Vendor 0x1a2c Product 0xc21
[559157.482] (--) evdev: USB USB Keyboard: Found 3 mouse buttons
[559157.482] (--) evdev: USB USB Keyboard: Found scroll wheel(s)
[559157.482] (--) evdev: USB USB Keyboard: Found relative axes
[559157.482] (--) evdev: USB USB Keyboard: Found x and y relative axes
[559157.482] (--) evdev: USB USB Keyboard: Found absolute axes
[559157.482] (II) evdev: USB USB Keyboard: Forcing absolute x/y axes to exist.
[559157.482] (--) evdev: USB USB Keyboard: Found keys
[559157.482] (II) evdev: USB USB Keyboard: Configuring as mouse
[559157.482] (II) evdev: USB USB Keyboard: Configuring as keyboard
[559157.482] (II) evdev: USB USB Keyboard: Adding scrollwheel support
[559157.482] (**) evdev: USB USB Keyboard: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[559157.482] (**) evdev: USB USB Keyboard: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[559157.482] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb3/3-5/3-5:1.1/input/input2/event2"
[559157.482] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "USB USB Keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[559157.482] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[559157.482] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc104"
[559157.482] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[559157.482] (**) Option "xkb_options" "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
[559157.482] (II) evdev: USB USB Keyboard: initialized for relative axes.
[559157.482] (WW) evdev: USB USB Keyboard: ignoring absolute axes.
[559157.482] (**) USB USB Keyboard: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[559157.483] (**) USB USB Keyboard: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[559157.483] (**) USB USB Keyboard: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[559157.483] (**) USB USB Keyboard: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[559157.483] (II) config/udev: Adding input device USB USB Keyboard (/dev/input/mouse1)
[559157.483] (**) USB USB Keyboard: Applying InputClass "Keyboard Defaults"
[559157.483] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[559157.483] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[559157.483] (II) config/udev: Adding input device PixArt USB Optical Mouse (/dev/input/event0)
[559157.483] (**) PixArt USB Optical Mouse: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[559157.483] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'PixArt USB Optical Mouse'
[559157.483] (**) PixArt USB Optical Mouse: always reports core events
[559157.483] (**) evdev: PixArt USB Optical Mouse: Device: "/dev/input/event0"
[559157.484] (--) evdev: PixArt USB Optical Mouse: Vendor 0x93a Product 0x2510
[559157.484] (--) evdev: PixArt USB Optical Mouse: Found 3 mouse buttons
[559157.484] (--) evdev: PixArt USB Optical Mouse: Found scroll wheel(s)
[559157.484] (--) evdev: PixArt USB Optical Mouse: Found relative axes
[559157.484] (--) evdev: PixArt USB Optical Mouse: Found x and y relative axes
[559157.484] (II) evdev: PixArt USB Optical Mouse: Configuring as mouse
[559157.484] (II) evdev: PixArt USB Optical Mouse: Adding scrollwheel support
[559157.484] (**) evdev: PixArt USB Optical Mouse: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[559157.484] (**) evdev: PixArt USB Optical Mouse: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[559157.484] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.0/usb4/4-1/4-1:1.0/input/input104/event0"
[559157.484] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "PixArt USB Optical Mouse" (type: MOUSE, id 10)
[559157.484] (II) evdev: PixArt USB Optical Mouse: initialized for relative axes.
[559157.484] (**) PixArt USB Optical Mouse: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[559157.484] (**) PixArt USB Optical Mouse: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[559157.484] (**) PixArt USB Optical Mouse: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[559157.484] (**) PixArt USB Optical Mouse: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[559157.484] (II) config/udev: Adding input device PixArt USB Optical Mouse (/dev/input/mouse0)
[559157.484] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[559157.484] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[559157.485] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HD-Audio Generic Front Headphone (/dev/input/event5)
[559157.485] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[559157.485] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[559157.485] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HD-Audio Generic Line Out (/dev/input/event6)
[559157.485] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[559157.485] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[559157.485] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HD-Audio Generic Line (/dev/input/event7)
[559157.485] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[559157.486] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[559157.486] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HD-Audio Generic Rear Mic (/dev/input/event8)
[559157.486] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[559157.486] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[559157.486] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HD-Audio Generic Front Mic (/dev/input/event9)
[559157.486] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[559157.486] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[559171.032] (II) VESA(0): Setting up VESA Mode 0x123 (1024x768)
[559198.930] (II) VESA(0): Setting up VESA Mode 0x123 (1024x768)
[559205.280] (II) VESA(0): Setting up VESA Mode 0x123 (1024x768)
[559225.875] (II) VESA(0): Setting up VESA Mode 0x123 (1024x768)
```

Comment: i also tried to change 24 to 32 (error) and to 16 (still starts at 1024x768)

Answer (score 1):

Do it using command line:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xrandr

**Get list of support resolutions:**

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1440 x 900, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
LVDS connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1440x900       59.9*+
   1280x854       59.9  
   1280x800       59.8
```

**Set resolution:**

```
$ xrandr --output LVDS --mode 1280x800
```

Comment: mine only shows: http://pastie.org/8229649

Answer (score 1):

This issue in the ArchLinux Newbie Corner titled: [[SOLVED]Issues with Vesa driver setting resolution](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=148412), sounds similar to yours. There are a couple of things highlighted in that thread that you can try.

The big one would be to make sure that you're not passing any kernel parameters related to your video card that might be co-opting the Vesa driver from doing it's thing.

Comment: no, `radeon` driver does not support my graphic card..